# Jquery Ajax call with GET parameters won't return nothing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, get

I want to retrive a detail of a video throught the redtube API. if i copy and paste the link in the browser all works fine
http://api.redtube.com/?data=redtube.Videos.getVideoById&video_id=15485&output=json&thumbsize=all

Note: May be offensive to some users, it's a porn API.

But when i attempt to receive the json object throught an ajax call, no result is given and the call goes in error

```
$.ajax({
      url : 'http://api.redtube.com/?data=redtube.Videos.getVideoById&video_id=15485&output=json&thumbsize=all',
      dataType : 'json',
      success: function (res) 
                {
                 alert (res)

                },
     error : function (res) {alert(res.code);}      
})
```

Why?

Comment: Heads up! The images in that API call are very **NSFW**.

Comment: Ever heard of same origin policy?

Comment: I dunno, I just had three chocolate sticks at my desk. Nobody complained, in fact we shared.

Comment: Look at your javascript error console. You are being blocked by the same origin policy. See if their API has a jsonp option, or do the API call on the server.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery Cross Domain Ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16989505/jquery-cross-domain-ajax)

Comment: WTF. at least change the URL

Comment: And can i perform the call from server side in php ? Same origin policy is only for client side right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make AJAX call to the API due to same-origin policy. Learn more about it [here](http://enable-cors.org/)

Comment: and can i perform the call from server side and pass to ajax? I always done that

Comment: yes, you can call the API from server and make AJAX call to your own server.