# Alert text from file JQuery / javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can't get these simple things to work, I have an text file with some text in it and I want an alert containing the text thats inside of a text file to be triggered when clicking a "btn/link".

Also I want to be able to compare and see if the text inside the file is true or false:

[**JSFIDDLE demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/nzu3udxn/)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="alert_btn"><a href="javascript:alert_fn();">click_me</a></div>
```

**JQuery/javascript:**

```
function alert_fn(){
    $.get('http://www.patan77.com/example_test.txt', function(data) {
        alert(data);
        if (data == true){
            alert("true");
        }else{
            alert("false");
        }
    });   
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: cross domain request. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'.

Comment: data is not of boolean type so **if (data == true){** cannot be true. you can check **if(data)** for checking the response is not a null value. For cross domain ajax request refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16989505/jquery-cross-domain-ajax

Comment: Found that in Chrome DevTools (f12) then under network its possible to disable cache (the DevTools need to be open when refreshing the page for it to work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think I got it working now.

**[Test_DEMO](http://www.patan77.com/test_alert.html)**

HTML with jQuery / Javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="1" />
<title>Test_Alert</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

function alert_fn(){
    $.get('http://www.patan77.com/example_test.txt', function(data) {
       alert(data);
    });   
}


function alert_fn_2(){
    $.get('http://www.patan77.com/example_test.txt', function(data) {
        var text_file = data;

        if (text_file == "hello world"){
            alert ("its true");
        }else{
            alert ("its false");
        }

    });
}

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="alert_btn"><a href="javascript:alert_fn();">click_me</a></div>
<div id="alert_btn_2"><a href="javascript:alert_fn_2();">click_me_to_see_if_true</a></div>
v.06
</body>
</html>
```