# Facebook Json Deserialize C# data from

Tags: c#, json, facebook-graph-api, import, deserialization

Facebook Json Deserialize C# data from

```
    "comments": {
      "data": [
        {
          "id": "10202845951538899_6903133", 
          "from": {
            "name": "Name Surname", 
            "id": "1514294282"
          }, 
          "message": "Statuses Comment", 
          "can_remove": true, 
          "created_time": "2013-12-11T15:49:35+0000", 
          "like_count": 0, 
          "user_likes": false
        }
      ]
```

How to json comment data from **id name** access

thanks.

Comment: this could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257117/json-string-to-js-object

Comment: thanks but this result not compatible, facebook json data I reach

Comment: I can't get access to the comments but the name and id

"from": {
            "name": "Name Surname", 
            "id": "1514294282"

I want to access this data.

Comment: try to search about jsonsoft.net

Answer (score 0):

Simple example of deserializing into a C# class using Newtonsoft Json.

If you do not have this package use Nuget to install it:

```
Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json
```

Program.cs (console app)

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace test
{

    public class FbData
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public FbCommentBy from { get; set; }
        public string message { get; set; }
        public string can_remove { get; set; }
    }

    public class FbCommentBy
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
    }

    public class FbComments
    {
        public List<FbData> data { get; set; }
    }

    public class FbWrapper
    {
        public FbComments comments { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string fbJson = @"{
   'comments':{
      'data':[
         {
            'id':'10202845951538899_6903133',
            'from':{
               'name':'Name Surname',
               'id':'1514294282'
            },
            'message':'Statuses Comment',
            'can_remove':true,
            'created_time':'2013-12-11T15:49:35+0000',
            'like_count':0,
            'user_likes':false
         }
      ]
   }
}";

            FbWrapper wrapper = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FbWrapper>(fbJson);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I'm on facebook data