# Get value from Javascript JSON object by referencing specific property name

Tags: javascript, json, object, google-apps-script, google-admin-sdk

I'm using Google Apps Script (Javascript) to retrieve the details of a user using the [Users.get method](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/get) in the [Google Apps Admin SDK Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/).

The code to get the user is:

```
var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users/'+email+'?key='+publicApiAccessKey;
var scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly";

var fetchArgs = googleOAuth_("Users",scope);
fetchArgs.method = "GET";
fetchArgs.muteHttpExceptions=true;

var userObject = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, fetchArgs);
```

The response is a [Google Apps Admin SDK User resource](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users#resource) and object in this format:

```
{
  "kind": "admin#directory#user",
  "id": string,
  "etag": etag,
  "primaryEmail": string,
  "name": {
    "givenName": string,
    "familyName": string,
    "fullName": string
  },
  "isAdmin": boolean,
  "isDelegatedAdmin": boolean,
  "lastLoginTime": datetime,
  // rest of the properties excluded
}
```

How do I get the value of **fullName**?

Here's what I tried so far, with no success:

```
Logger.log( Object.prototype.toString.call(userObject) ); // returns [object JavaObject]
Logger.log( userObject.name.fullName ); // Cannot read property "fullName" from undefined.
Logger.log( userObject.fullName ); // undefined
Logger.log( userObject.name ); // undefined
Logger.log( userObject['fullName'] ); // undefined
Logger.log( userObject['name'] ); // undefined
Logger.log( userObject['name','fullName'] ); // undefined
```

Comment: `userObject` is clearly not the object described. If it were, then your `userObject.name.fullName` would be correct. I would suggest `Logger.log(userObject);` and/or `for (var name in userObject) { Logger.log(name); }` and/or `Object.prototype.toString.call(userObject);` to figure out what it is. For instance, could it be an *array*? `typeof anArray` returns `"object"`. I can't see why it would return an array, but...

Comment: Hmm, ok. `Object.prototype.toString.call(userObject)` returns `[object JavaObject]` and `for (var name in userObject) { Logger.log(name); }` seems to just list the methods of the object (same as the autocomplete code suggestions I get when you type userObject followed by a dot: `[14-07-27 17:21:45:843 EDT] getResponseCode
[14-07-27 17:21:45:843 EDT] getContentText
[14-07-27 17:21:45:844 EDT] getContent
[14-07-27 17:21:45:844 EDT] getAs
[14-07-27 17:21:45:844 EDT] getHeaders
[14-07-27 17:21:45:844 EDT] getBlob
[14-07-27 17:21:45:845 EDT] toString
[14-07-27 17:21:45:845 EDT] getAllHeaders`

Comment: Side note: If it's been deserialized (and if `typeof` says anything other than `"string"` it has been), it's not a "JSON object" anymore. It's an object. JSON is a *textual* notation for data interchange.

Comment: Nope, nothing to do with Java, but not sure if it's related to GWT. I'm running this code in the Google Apps Script Script editor, which is basically sandboxed Javascript. What's confusing to me is that in [the documentation for this get method](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/get), it just says _If successful, this method returns an Users resource in the response body._, and the page describing the resource says "The following JSON template is used for Users resources in the Directory API" but doesn't tell you how to retrieve values from it.

Comment: Found it: (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response). Let me do some reading on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As T.J. helped me discover, the Google Apps Script UrlFetchApp.fetch() method does not return a Javascript object. It returns what is basically a string that is structured in JSON notation, but it needs to be parsed first. There is a built-in library in Google Apps Script for Parsing JSON-structured strings.

Here is the final, working code:

```
var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users/'+email+'?key='+publicApiAccessKey;
var scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly";

var fetchArgs = googleOAuth_("Users",scope);
fetchArgs.method = "GET";
fetchArgs.muteHttpExceptions=false;

var userJson = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, fetchArgs);

var userObject = JSON.parse(userJson);

var fullName = userObject.name.fullName;
```

I learned about JSON.parse() [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24985649/get-value-from-javascript-json-object-by-referencing-specific-property-name).

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment to the question, I suspect you've done something like this:

```
var userObject = Users.get(/*...args...*/);
```

...in whatever layer you're using to get the response, and so `userObject` isn't the user object, it's some form of custom XHR-like object. The documentation you've linked to is specifically Java and Python, not browser-side. (Barring using a Java applet, of course.)

Check that documentation, most likely it expects you to provide a callback/lambda or call a method on that object (`getContent` looked tempting) to get the actual response.

Comment: Updated my original question to include the API call which returns the object, for clarification. `userObject.getContent()` returns an array of integers (strange), perhaps they are string lengths? `userObject.getContentText()` returns the text of the object but in the [object String] type. I'm going to go see if I can find the Google Apps Script documentation for these types of objects.

Comment: Figured it out: the HTTP GET request response contains data in JSON notation, but it needs to be parsed first, and Google Apps Script has a built-in JSON parsing library called `JSON.parse` which I learned about [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257117/json-string-to-js-object). Thanks for pointing me in the right direction to help me realize it wasn't a valid Object type.

Comment: @mike: You're welcome! I suggest you post the correct way to process the call as an answer, and in a couple of days when SO lets you, accept your answer. The above got you started, but you got it across the finishing line, and from what you've described the above is incomplete (e.g., for others finding this in the future). :-)