# How to create JSON object from json string with multiple objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a json string like this

```
{
 [
  {"plan": "basic", "plan_id": "sub33"},
  {"plan": "advanced", "plan_id: "sub44"}
 ]
}
```

How can I create a JSON object from the above?

When I try to parse it I get an error:

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( '{[{"plan": "basic", "plan_id": "sub33"},{"plan": "advanced", "plan_id: "sub44"}]}' );
(program):1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [
var obj = jQuery.parse( '{[{"plan": "basic", "plan_id": "sub33"},{"plan": "advanced", "plan_id: "sub44"}]}' );
VM8143:2 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Comment: what u want see at finish?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSON string to JS object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257117/json-string-to-js-object)

Comment: He has mistake at unclose ' " ', and how do u get { [] }, where the key of hash?

Comment: After "plan_id: "sub44"}  must be "plan_id": "sub44"}

Comment: and JSON.parse - not a jQuery.parse

Comment: Why are you writing JSON by hand anyway? Why aren't you making it an actual object directly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you need valid JSON. Your example isn't valid, it needs a key for the array, e.g.:

```
{
 "array": [
  {"plan": "basic", "plan_id": "sub33"},
  {"plan": "advanced", "plan_id": "sub44"}
 ]
}
```

**Or**, if you just want an array and not an object wrapper around it:

```
[
  {"plan": "basic", "plan_id": "sub33"},
  {"plan": "advanced", "plan_id": "sub44"}
]
```

> How can I create a JSON object from the above?

You don't, you already have a "JSON object" (**text** that defines an object). JSON is a textual notation for data exchange; when you turn it into objects in memory, it's not text anymore, so it's not JSON anymore. (Just like a DOM element isn't an HTML string, even though it may have been *created from* an HTML string.)

To turn it into a JavaScript object, you use `JSON.parse` (`jQuery.parseJSON` is fine too, and useful for really old browsers, but all modern browsers have `JSON.parse` now):

```
var obj = JSON.parse(yourString);
```

Example:

```js
var yourString = '{' +
    '"array": ' +
    ' [' +
    '  {"plan": "basic", "plan_id": "sub33"},' +
    '  {"plan": "advanced", "plan_id": "sub44"}' +
    ' ]' +
    '}';
var obj = JSON.parse(yourString);
snippet.log(obj.array[0].plan); // "basic"
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Or if you just want the array:

Example:

```js
var yourString =
    '[' +
    '  {"plan": "basic", "plan_id": "sub33"},' +
    '  {"plan": "advanced", "plan_id": "sub44"}' +
    ']';
var array = JSON.parse(yourString);
snippet.log(array[0].plan); // "basic"
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply be removing excessive {}. And correcting typo "plan_id**"**:

```
var x = [
  {"plan": "basic", "plan_id": "sub33"},
  {"plan": "advanced", "plan_id": "sub44"}
];
```

//x is JS object. JSON is notation, not a constructor.
You can stringify to send over the wire, like JSON.stringify(x), this will give you a JSON-string: "[{"plan":"basic","plan_id":"sub33"},{"plan":"advanced","plan_id":"sub44"}]"

Answer (score -2):

You can use JSON.parse(jsonString)