# Array is not serialized and resulting a string

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, arrays, serialization

A list that contains a set of arrays is being serialized into jquery. However when check in client side, it is receiving only a string instead of the array object.

c#:

```
public string jsscript(){
// datatable processing
    var arrList = new List<object>();

    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        string name = row[0].ToString();
        string quantity = row[1].ToString();
        string balance = row[2].ToString();
        string remove = "X";

        arrList.Add( new[] { name, quantity, balance, remove });
    }

    return (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(arrList);
 }
```

js:

```
<script>
    //dom... 
    function theDomHasLoaded(e) {
            dbdata = <%=jsscripts()%>;  

</script>
```

Comment: but the point of serialise is to generate a json string... Are you expecting an object? You'll need to use JSON.parse(...)

Comment: What does that `<script>` block look like when you do a "View source" on the completed page?

Comment: @daveL Then I am missing `JSON.parse`.

Comment: @Pointy View Source : `dbdata = [["Jorge","25","20","X"],["Jacques","50","10","X"],["Bell","10","10","X"]];  ` it's in proper format But when `alert(dbdata)` : it's just a string delimited by comma.

Comment: I have no idea why someone voted this to be an off topic: `This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center.`...

Comment: @aspiring that's because when you pass the array to `alert()` it's forced to be a string; that's just what `alert()` does. Use `console.log()` instead - it's much more useful.

Answer (score 0):

see [JSON string to JS object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257117/json-string-to-js-object)

you need to use JSON.parse(..) on the serialised string

that is of course presuming that that is the problem... It's not entirely clear what your problem is.

Comment: This is not necessarily the right thing to do. If that serializer really creates a JSON string, then dropping the string straight into JavaScript will result in a valid JavaScript object initializer expression, because JSON is valid JavaScript. There should be no need to embed a string containing JSON and then explicitly parse it.

Comment: @Pointy dbdata will be initialised as a string... as the server will just write a string to the aspx/view page and then send that to the client. The client does not see that as json. Just a string.

Comment: You (the client) are not receiving anything. The server writes the string to the aspx/view and then serves that to the client. The client does not see a json object. It sees a string. If you want the client to have an object; you'll need to create an object from that string.

Comment: If client is not seeing a JSON object, why is this happening? It fails to convert here. After using `JSON.parse` I get this in View Source : `dbdata = JSON.parse([["Jorge","25","20","X"],["Jacques","50","10","X"],["Bell","10","10","X"]]);`

Comment: Why would it be seeing a JSON object? You are writing a string to the page on the server not returning a json string with a mime type of application/json

Comment: It's returning a JSON string without `JSON.parse`, otherwise what's the meaning of `JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize` this code and view source in this format `dbdata = [["Jorge","25","20","X"],["Jacques","50","10","X"],["Bell","10","10","X"]];`? It looks like something else, which you and I both are unaware seems to happen...

Comment: @daveL see the comment the OP added to the question. As I suspected, the JSON is being dumped directly into the `<script>` source, where it will be successfully parsed as a JavaScript object literal. The root problem here is that the OP was confused about what the diagnostic `alert()` call was showing; that's all. The client **does** see a JavaScript object, because the ASP code dumps the JSON directly into the JavaScript code unquoted.

Comment: @Pointy I've personal experience of doing something exactly like this... And my experience says that it is nothing more than a string. I'd do a demo if I had the time but I don't..